# Fancy Box IE error 'console' is undefined

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i add fancy box in the fanpage of facebook. when i click on image first time it works well. at the 2nd time after i come on page again i only see black screen no with image and content of the popup. can any one tell me whats wrong with this.

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
    Timestamp: Wed, 6 Jun 2012 09:21:33 UTC


Message: 'console' is undefined
Line: 688
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: https://url.com/fanpages/health-stream/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js?v=6
```

Comment: looks like you have a `console.log` or something else hanging around somewhere. Remove it or wrap it with `(if window.console){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE hasn't console variable in namespace. 
Find:

```
console.log( something )
```

And wrap it with:

```
if(console != undefined) {
    console.log( something );
}
```

Comment: What if Kashif used `console.info` and there would be something like `undefined = console` in the code? >.<

Comment: true, but he should know what he used. And in client-release all console requests should be removed.

Comment: Thanks Kasyx. You give me a perfecy answere

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not have the `console` property as long as the developer console is not opened.

You can work around this by wrapping the console call with (and remove for production version):

```
if(window.console){
        console....
}
```

If you come back on the page then the console is closed and thus the missing `console` property causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

i awas add a code for fit poup frame in the window. 
the error was for this line `console.log(window.canvasInfo);`
juch add condition on this line and soved my problem.

```
                     if(window.console){
                        console.log(window.canvasInfo);
                      }
```

Thanks you all.